# Why is map marker blown up on first load?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-tv

I am using Google Maps API V3 on server side and loading in a WebView on GoogleTV application.  On the first load my marker image is distorted, but if I use the zoom controls, it reloads appropriately and proportionally. I have attached 2 screen shots:

First Load (incorrect):
[image]

zoom in and out (correct);

[image]

Here is my updateView with the center Url call:

```
    private void updateView(){
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, " updateView()");

    // added 
    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mapWebView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    Double lat = 0.0;
    Double lon = 0.0;
    lat = Double.parseDouble(mWd.getCurrentWeatherDataModel().lat);
    lon = Double.parseDouble(mWd.getCurrentWeatherDataModel().lon);
    final String centerURL = "javascript:mpSetCenter(" + lat + "," + lon + ")";
    if (mWebView != null) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setZoomLevel(" + mZoomLevel + ")");
                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onPageFinished() b4 dimiss dialogs");
                Dialogs.dismiss();
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mWebView.loadUrl(centerURL);
                    }
                }, 1000);

                if (mWd.getCurrentWeatherDataModel().overlayOption.equals(RADAR_OVERLAY)) {
                    mIsRadarShowing = true;
                    mIsSatelliteShowing = false;
                } else {
                    mIsRadarShowing = false;
                    mIsSatelliteShowing = true;
                }
                init();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Error, oh noes! " + description);
            }
        });
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
             @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                 Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "message in onJsAlert is " + message);
                    result.confirm();
                    return true;
                }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/maps_v3.html"); 
        Dialogs.dismiss();
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "dismiss b4 this stmnt and showLoadingDialog after");
        Dialogs.showLoadingDialog((android.app.Activity) mContext);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30000);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why??

Here is the js file portion that creates marker:

```
//Center map on lat/lon of chosen location.
function mpSetCenter(lat, lon) {
    var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    clearMarkers();
    map.setCenter(centerPoint);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: centerPoint, 
      map: map
  }); 
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
  marker_list.push(marker);
}
```

Comment: Two questions to clarify:

1) Do you see the same strange behavior loading centerURL in Chrome on the device?
2) How are you creating that marker? KML?

Comment: I added the code from the js file that creates the marker.  This issue is only seen on Google TV (XHDPI and TVDPI), as well as a tablet I have that is pulling from the TVDPI.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do see the same behavior when loading in Chrome/browser on device.

Comment: What's the MINSDK & TargetSDK in your manifest?  What version of Google TV are you using (Sony v2.1, or Revue v2.0)?